# Where does docker desktop "start on login" option get stored and how to stop Docker from doing this outside of docker desktop?

Tags: macos, startup, docker

MacOS start applications are controlled through the user and groups settings.

Also you can use cron.

In docker desktop there is a login setting that seems to secretly put some login setting somewhere. WHERE? This should be banned. Secret login triggers are a virus and security threat.

Is it in root and macos doesn't show root?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/390498/how-to-stop-applications-opening-on-login

Answer (score 2):

To disable docker from starting up when you log in:

Click on the docker icon on the menu bar and select preferences:

Disable the checkbox which says "Start Docker Desktop when you log in". Hope that helps.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is good to clarify for anyone landing here but my question is about where this is on the macos side. Like suppose I didn't want to even launch docker to turn this off.